# How do I select this with HTMLAgility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

From this HTML

```
<div class="sBody text wd_select_m_down" id="id_language" rel="2">Italiano</div>
```

I want to Select it from this code. But it didn't stop.

```
do
                {
                    htmldoc.LoadHtml(web_scrape); //to get current webpage source
                    SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                } while ((htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@rel,'2')]") == null));
```

Anyone have an idea to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My reponse is only for XPath part. 
I did not understand what are you trying to do exactly. It seems you want to press “down” key as long as where is NO desired element (Please correct me if I’m wrong on this) .

You are trying to select a DIV, but used SPAN in your xpath selector.

Now,
If you want all DIVs with rel=”2”, you can use this xpath :

```
//div[@rel=’2’]
```

If you want ALL elements with rel = “2”, you can use

```
//*[@rel=’2’]
```

Comment: Your Xpath is ok but I will try it out and fix something because something is not right. But Thank you :D

Comment: Press down until they found the element (it's dropdown list) name "Italiano". Could you help me out again? Thank you.